# runtime error '438' object dosent support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I try to run my code but get a runtime error when I try to store the variables in sht1 and sht2 to get the worksheets based on index

ive tried to set the array "lasSheets(i) and dataPull(i)" to sht1 and sht2 so it can just select the array value at index i but I get a "compiler error: Expected Sub, Function or Property" so i ran out of ideas of what to do next

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim source As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mapDest As String
    Dim mapSrc As String

    setFile = Application.GetOpenFilename   'used to open the browser window
    tmp = setFile                           'store the selected file in variable tmp
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      'preventing long runtimes

    If Dir(tmp) <> "" Then
    Set destination = ThisWorkbook     'workbook b1 is declared as the current worksheet opened
    Set source = Workbooks.Open(tmp)      'the file the user selected is opened in excel

    Dim lasSheets(1 To 9) As String        'array to list the sheet names

    lasSheets(1) = "L1 OVERVIEW"
    lasSheets(2) = "LAS EFFL RELEASE PARAMS"
    lasSheets(3) = "L1 EAL PARAMS rev4"
    lasSheets(4) = "L1 EAL PARAMS"
    lasSheets(5) = "L1 RAD STATUS"
    lasSheets(6) = "L1 PLANT STATUS"
    lasSheets(7) = "L1 CDAM"
    lasSheets(8) = "L1 ERDS"
    lasSheets(9) = "LAS STATE UPDATES"

    Dim dataPull(1 To 9) As String
    dataPull(1) = "Overview Paste"
    dataPull(2) = "Eff Release Para Paste"
    dataPull(3) = "EAL Rev4 Paste"
    dataPull(4) = "EAL Para Paste"
    dataPull(5) = "Radiological Stat Paste"
    dataPull(6) = "Plant Status Paste"
    dataPull(7) = "CDAM Paste"
    dataPull(8) = "ERDS Paste"  ' blank sheet
    dataPull(9) = "State Updates Paste"   'blank sheet

    For i = 1 To 9
      mapSrc = lasSheets(i)
      mapDest = dataPull(i)
    i = i + 1
     Set sht1 = source.Sheet(mapSrc)            '<-- errors here set sht1 and sht2 to the source and destination worksheets   
     Set sht2 = destination.Sheet(mapDest)  

    Set startCell = sht1.Range("B2")

    'find last row and last column
     lastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
     lastColumn = sht1.Cells(startCell.Row, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

     sht2.Range(startCell, sht1.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Address).Copy destination:=sht1.Range("D5")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    destination.Close True

    Else                                'used to prevent a error message from popping up when the user choose to cancel selecting a file

    End If
    End Sub
```

I expect the for loop to loop through both the arrays and output the excel worksheets based on index number within both the arrays

Comment: `Sheets` not `Sheet`.

Comment: i get a runtime error for that also which is subscript is out of range

Comment: Then there's no sheet of that name in the workbook.

Comment: the excel workbook has multiple sheets but i only want certain sheets that can be used for simulations. so i only mapped the worksheets that are needed for running sims

Comment: I figured it out thanks

Comment: It would be good if you could post your solution.